# Search for list of strings in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings that I want to search.

```
strings = ['Tea','Baseball','Onus']
```

My dataframe is

```
   itemid   desc
0  101      tea leaves
1  201      baseball gloves
3  221      teas leaves from Onus Green Tea Co.
```

I want to get something like this, without considering partial matches

```
   itemid   desc                                 matches
0  101      tea leaves                           [Tea]
1  201      baseball gloves                      [Baseball]
2  221      teas leaves from Onus Green Tea Co.   [Tea, Onus]
```

I am doing this

```
import re
df['desc'] = df.desc.str.split(' ')
df['desc'].str.findall('|'.join(strings),flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

but it is giving me a series of empty commas

```
0     [(, , , , , ), (, , , , , ), (, , , , , )]
1     [(, , , , , ), (, , , , , ), (, , , , , )]
2     [(, , , , , ), (, , , , , ), (, , , , , )]
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Edit: I do not want partial matches. Updated example to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Series.str.findall` with the regex ignore case flag (`?i`), this way we dont have to use `import re`

```
df['Matches'] = df['desc'].str.findall(f'(?i)({"|".join(strings)})')

   itemid                                desc           Matches
0     101                          tea leaves             [tea]
1     201                     baseball gloves        [baseball]
2     221  tea leaves from Onus Green Tea Co.  [tea, Onus, Tea]
```

To remove duplicates, we cast your strings to upper case and make a `set`:

```
df['Matches'] = (
    df['desc'].str.findall(f'(?i)({"|".join(strings)})')
    .apply(lambda x: list(set(map(str.upper, x))))
)
```

```
   itemid                                desc      Matches
0     101                          tea leaves        [TEA]
1     201                     baseball gloves   [BASEBALL]
2     221  tea leaves from Onus Green Tea Co.  [TEA, ONUS]
```

---

#### Edit for partial match

We can use word boundaries `\b` for this:

```
strings = ['\\b' + f + '\\b' for f in strings]

df['Matches'] = df['desc'].str.findall(f'(?i)({"|".join(strings)})')
```

```
   itemid                                 desc      Matches
0     101                           tea leaves        [tea]
1     201                      baseball gloves   [baseball]
2     221  teas leaves from Onus Green Tea Co.  [Onus, Tea]
```

Comment: is there any way to avoid partial matches?

Comment: i have edited and updated the question and example.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to spit the `desc` column.

```
import re
strings = ['Tea','Baseball','Onus']     
df = pd.DataFrame({"desc": ['tea leaves', 'baseball gloves', 'tea leaves from Onus Green Tea Co.']})
df['matches'] = df['desc'].str.findall('|'.join(strings),flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(df['matches'])
```

**Output:**

```
0               [tea]
1          [baseball]
2    [tea, Onus, Tea]
Name: matches, dtype: object
```

Comment: is there any way to avoid partial matches?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `contains` with a regex alternation:

```
strings = ['Tea','Baseball','Onus']
rgx = '\\b(?:' + '|'.join(strings) + ')\\b'
df[df.desc.str.contains(rgx, regex=True, na=False)]
```